# Find max value in Hashmap and return the minumum key

Tags: java, hashmap

I have an array of integers and I want to know which number has been repeated more than the others.If we have two numbers which repeated same my program should return the number with min index.

For example : I have an array list which save below nums.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(9);
list.add(0);
list.add(1);
list.add(1);
list.add(9);
```

so I created Hashmap to save the number as key and its frequency as Value

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> list1 = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    list1.put(list.get(i), Collections.frequency(list, list.get(i)));
}
```

Since I have two numbers "1,9" which repeated same as each other "2 times"
my program should return 1 because one has minumum index.
so how can I fin max value in hashmap and return the minumum index

Comment: *"Since I have two numbers "1,9" which repeated same as each other "2 times" my program should return 1 because one has minumum index"* Huh? You have 9 at index 0. Doesn't get much more minimum than that. :-)

Comment: Applearently, the numbers in the list are representing indices of some kind.

Comment: You can use a TreeSet since we can iterate through the keys by the keys' natural ordering

Comment: You code is really very inefficient - it runs on `O(n^2)` time. `O(n)` is fully possible. `stream()` the `List` then `groupingBy` with `counting()`. Finally `stream()` the `Map.entries()` and `maxBy` `Entry.getValue` then `Entry.getKey`.

Comment: The hash map as you currently use it is completely useless and makes things more difficult. Hint: don't use `Collections.frequency`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to use the `groupingBy` collector instead of `frequency` and then leverage the stream API to apply further operations to refine your query.

```
 Optional<Integer> key = list.stream() // Stream<Integer>
            .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), counting())) // Map<Integer, Long>
            .entrySet().stream() //Stream<Entry<Integer, Long>>
            .max(Comparator.comparingLong((ToLongFunction<Map.Entry<Integer, Long>>) Map.Entry::getValue)
                    .thenComparingInt(s -> -s.getKey())) // Optional<Entry<Integer, Long>> // Optional<Entry<Integer, Long>>
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey); //Optional<Integer>
```

- supplying the `groupingBy` collector to the `collect` method allows us to group each element in the source `list` and as a result have a `Map<Integer, Long>` where each entry represents the element and the number of times it occurs in the source `list`.
- we then find the max value in Hashmap and return the minimum key.
- Finally, we have a `Optional<Integer>` containing the key otherwise an empty optional.

Running this code against the sample data you've provided this will retrieve the number `1` which meets your requirements.

Since you mentioned that the numbers in the list represent indices this should suffice.

---

If you're not familiar with the `Optional<T>` API then I'd suggest browsing the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `LinkedHashMap` to maintain the insertion order in the `Map` and then you can use lambda to index with max value which comes first in the index like below:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(9);
        list.add(0);
        list.add(1);
        list.add(1);
        list.add(9);

        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            map.put(list.get(i), Collections.frequency(list, list.get(i)));
        }
        System.out.println(map);
        System.out.println(Collections.max(map.entrySet(),
        Comparator.comparingInt(entry -> entry.getValue())).getKey());
```

***O/P:***

> {9=2, 0=1, 1=2}
>
> 9

If you want index with min key then replace above `LinkedHashMap` with below:

```
SortedMap<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
```

It will give `1` as output.

Comment: I think the user means lowest key by "index". As otherwise the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @BoristheSpider yes, if we use `LinkedHashMap` then `9` will be the first key in the map. Thus the result follows.

Comment: Yup. "_my program should return 1_". `9` is not `1`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider well it doesn't make any sense. Anyway in that case we need to use `SortedMap` instead of `LinkedHashMap`

Comment: Agreed. But answering a question by assuming the question is wrong is not a valid approach I'm afraid. This answer is wrong.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I agree. I've updated my answer with two solutions.